# Running a GUI requires opening the .fig file in GUIDE

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am trying to run a MATLAB GUI I have created. If I open the .fig file using GUIDE and press the run button there, it runs perfectly.

However, when I double-click the .fig file in the 'Current Folder' section of MATLAB, it seems to be unable to find the `handles` variable. This causes it to give an error whenever `handles` is used.

Why does this happen? Is there a fix/workaround?

I'm using MATLAB R2011, but I've tried it on R2012 as well. The code runs fine, and displays the GUI fine, but the moment it encounters the `handles` variable, it gives the following error:

**Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a GUI using GUIDE, it should create both a `.fig` file and a `.m` file. To run it, you should run the `.m` file, rather than double-clicking the `.fig` file.

The `.fig` file just contains static information about the layout of the GUI - there is nothing executable in it that would initialise `handles` and so on.

Comment: Thanks! That helps. However, I have one doubt. Why does it work when I open the figure in GUIDE and press the run button there?

Comment: Because that runs the `.m` file.

Comment: @shashwat Sam has the correct answer here. The GUI executes when you press the run button in GUIDE because GUIDE will look for an M-File with the same name as the figure you have opened. This doesn't work in the regular MATLAB workspace, because there's nothing telling MATLAB that your GUI is anything other than a standard figure.

Comment: Some more detail: A `.fig` file is actually a renamed `.zip` file. You can unzip it with WinZip or another compression tool. Inside it is a `.mat` file. Load it in, and you'll find it contains a regular MATLAB variable with a dump of the handles to all the axes and uicontrols etc in your GUI. There's nothing directly executable. Somewhere in there, I can't remember where, it also stores the name of the `.m` file associated with the GUI. When you load the figure into GUIDE, the run button runs that `.m` file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, always run `.m` file if you want to check your code and if you want to edit GUI go through **guide** command. If you open `.fig` file you'll get a file which you can't execute and you can't able to analyze that. corresponding `.m` file will have respective functions for your GUI.