# Browse Directory in MatLab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm new to Matlab and basically what I'm trying to do is create a GUI where it lets the user browse for a file they want to open and place the string onto an edit box right next to the browse button.

So far my code looks like this for the browse pushbutton

```
 function Select_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Select (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[filename,pathname]=uigetfile(...
{'*.csv';'*.xls';'*.xlsx'; '*.*';},'Select the Run Summaries File');
handles.filename=filename;
handles.pathname=pathname;



guidata(hObject,handles);
set(handles.RunSum,'String',[pathname filename]);
set(handles.Brows,'String',pathname);
```

RunSum is the tag for the edit box next to it. So far the GUI works fine when I run the .m file and the edit box changes its string successfully when a file is selected, however, when I run the GUI from the .fig file and I browse for a file, I keep getting this error:

```
Reference to non-existent field 'RunSum'.

Error in ID_analysis>Select_Callback (line 383)
set(handles.RunSum,'String',[pathname filename]);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
    feval(varargin{:});

Error in ID_analysis (line 42)
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)ID_analysis('Select_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

It mentions a reference to a non-existent field but in the script it's there and it does exist. Is there any other better way of making this browse button? I don't understand why the .fig file can't detect the edit tag 'RunSum' ?

Comment: Run the GUI from the .m-File: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678762/running-a-gui-requires-opening-the-fig-file-in-guide

Comment: Thank you, I was just wondering because there's another program I've seen that actually changes the edit box by selecting a file just from running the .fig file by itself.