# Open a GUI directly from desktop (Shortcut) in MATLAB environment

Tags: matlab, user-interface, shortcut

I want open a GUI directly from desktop without opening MATLAB and run it from it. When I right click on the main `MATLAB code` file and select `Run` in windows environment, MATLAB starts and after that my GUI automatically runs but I want have this with double clicking on an Icon (shortcut) o desktop. How can I do this? I don't want compile my app.

- My GUI contains training neural network so I can't compile it.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678762/running-a-gui-requires-opening-the-fig-file-in-guide

Comment: @Dev-iL. Thank you but technically I think I need a trick in windows and creating shortcut to run the code not open it.

Comment: What you want, is to be able to double click `.m` files and have them execute in MATLAB. It is not something specific for GUIs. Which OS are you using?

Comment: Yes. That's true. as you said we don't need any changing in codes because when we right click on the file and select run we can run it directly in windows environment. We want some trick to create a shortcut to run not open the file.

Comment: The only way possible I think other than creating an app, would be creating an EXE with `mcc`.

Comment: @Divakar. The problem is my GUI contains training neural network so I can't compile it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you actually need is a way to run `.m` files via the command line - an action which isn't specific to GUIs. A command line operation is something you can bind to a shortcut on your desktop or execute using a batch file.

The solution you're looking for is a combination of [MATLAB-specific syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6717782/3372061) and a [straightforward batch file creation procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6717782/3372061):

1. Open a text editor.
2. Write this inside:
   `"C:\<path to your MATLAB folder>\matlab.exe" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "cd('C:\<path to your where the .m file is>\'); run('C:\<path to where the .m file is>\mfile.m');"`
3. Save the file as `.bat` (in windows) and run.

Comment: Thank you. Now GUI will open but I cant do anything. For example when I click on push buttons I have errors like this : `Undefined function 'Main_page' for input arguments of type 'struct'.` . Main_page is my running .m file of GUI.

Comment: I added something like `cd F:\Files_Path_of_my_program` in first line of text file but it didn't work. What is the true structure of this code in text file you mentioned?

Comment: I'm working on it but the problem is this : is used something like : `-r "cd('C:\<a long path here>');"` in the end of code but MATLAB don't run this code. When I put this code in middle, Matlab don't run last code (running gui). What should I do?. When we have to command everything is good but when be add third command, Matlab don't run third command.

Comment: Please update your question with the things you tried so far and the things you want to achieve. It's hard {for me} to follow the comments + it seems like you're asking a whole different question now. Moreover, following your reply to Divakar's comment, note that it's helpful to add information like why you don't want to compile the code - if readers see the big picture, they can help you better.

Comment: I added a question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126193/find-user-document-address-from-matlab