# Error with Guide: Attempt to reference field of non-structure array

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am trying to use a gui I did in MATLAB using GUIDE, when I double click on the .fig file and fill the text field and press on the push button, I have the following error message, but if I right click on it and select edit with GUIDE then pressed run figure (the green triangle), when I fill the value and press on the button, it works normally and gives me the results.

Error message:

```
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in FYP>pushbutton1_Callback (line 474)
d1min = str2double(get(handles.d1min,'String'));

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in FYP (line 16)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)FYP('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Comment: In order to run the GUI you have to run it from the editor, i.e. the .m file generated by GUIDE instead of the .fig file. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678762/running-a-gui-requires-opening-the-fig-file-in-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an extension of my comment, here is what the doc says about .fig and .m files generated by GUIDE (available [here)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/files-generated-by-guide.html):

> By default, the first time you save or run a GUI, GUIDE stores the GUI
> in two files:
>
> A FIG-file, with extension .fig, that contains a complete description
> of the GUI layout and each UI component, such as push buttons, axes,
> panels, menus, and so on. The FIG-file is a binary file and you cannot
> modify it except by changing the layout in GUIDE. FIG-files are
> specializations of MAT-files. See Writing Custom Applications to Read
> and Write MAT-Files for more information.
>
> A code file, with extension .m, that initially contains initialization
> code and templates for some callbacks that control GUI behavior. You
> generally add callbacks you write for your UI components to this file.
> As the callbacks are functions, the GUI code file can never be a
> MATLAB® script.

So as you see you need to run the .m file in order to launch the GUI. Hope it's a bit clearer now :)