# Error: Attempt to reference field of non-structure array. Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, reference

I have a error only when run the archive.fig, when the program run the .m is not any problem, I searched in some websites but nothing. Thanks

**The error:**

```
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in Cramer>pushbutton2_Callback (line 128)
n = str2double(get(handles.edit1,'String'));

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in Cramer (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)Cramer('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

**My code:**

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

n = str2double(get(handles.edit1,'String'));

num = cell(n,n);
num(:,:) = {''};
set(handles.uitable1,'Data',num);
set(handles.uitable1,'ColumnEditable',true());

num = cell(n,1);
num(:,:)={''};
set(handles.uitable2,'Data',num);
set(handles.uitable2,'ColumnEditable',true());
```

Please help me.

Comment: You can't run a .fig file; you need to use the .m file. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193362/error-with-guide-attempt-to-reference-field-of-non-structure-array/27193961#27193961

Comment: Right, but my code call a .fig file and  run. I callback with this line: ` openfig('file.fig') ` Only when archive.fig contains matrices is when error appears.

Comment: Oh ok I see sorry about that I misunderstood your question!